# Why does reordering the terms of an infinite series make it convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

Why does rearranging terms in an infinite series make two series convergent and divergent for the same values. Shouldn't the sum be the same. After all we are not adding new terms. Can someone explain the concept behind it?

For example from wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function):

$\zeta(s) = \sum n^{-s}, \Re(s) > 1$

An extension of the area of convergence can be obtained by rearranging the original series.The series

$\zeta(s) = 1/(s-1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac {n} {{(n+1)}^s} - \frac {n-s} {n^s})$ converges for $\Re(s) > 0$

I know it has to do something with conditional convergence. But intuitively I am struggling to see why it works since the set of values in both series is same/unique the sum must also be unique. Or are we doing sum jugglery here relative to some predefined definition of what it means to be convergent or divergent? Sum of the values of any set must be unique so why does ordering matter?

Comment: Possibly relevant to your interests: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence

Comment: What you observe and object to is (as you suggest) a consequence of the definition of convergence. You have to abandon that or train your intuition.

Comment: Do you mean $(n+1)^s?$ Because $n+1^s=n+@.$

Comment: Here's an entertaining video that explains this topic in a way you might like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VO2A6I3Woos

Comment: @EthanBolker So as I interpret the conditional convergence and the set approaches are incompatible/contradictory. And we by definition choose the conditional approach.

Comment: I wouldn't call this re-arranging - that usually means permuting the terms, not changing the terms dramatically. For a simpler example, consider the function $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$  defined on $|x|<1$ can be extended to $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x+1)^n}{2^{n+1}}$$ for $|x+1|<2,$ which includes all $|x|<1.$ (Of course, the maximal extension of $f$ is $f(x)=1/(1-x).$)

Comment: Because we are actually not summing all the numbers. We are only looking at the limiting value when we sum a large amount of terms. Think of the series $1 -1/2 +1/3 -1/4 +\ldots$. Take 100 terms in this series. You get $(1 +1/3 + \ldots  + 1/99) -( 1/2 +1/4 +\ldots + 1/100)$. Now rearrange it as $1 +1/3 + 1/5 -1/2 + \ldots$ In this series after 100 terms you get $(1 + 1/3 + \ldots + 1/149) - (1/2 + \ldots + 1/50)$. You see the difference? Now $100$ isn't big but think about a billion terms! Apparently this difference won't show up if the series was absolutely convergent.

Comment: thanks to all of you for the comments. @HallaSurvivor Thank you so much for that video. its enlightening!